# Hyper-V 2019 Converged Network

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I think I have confused myself here, I have 2 nodes with windows server 2019. I plan on creating a converged network using 5 10gb NICs.

I will create a NIC Team called 'Converged-vSW', the 5 NICs will be bound to the vSwitch. I will then create 5 vNICS via powershell:

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name “Managment” -SwitchName “Converged-vSW”
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name “VMData” -SwitchName “Converged-vSW”
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name “Cluster” -SwitchName “Converged-vSW”
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name “Live Migration” -SwitchName “Converged-vSW”
```

This is where I get confused, for my VM's, do I:

1. Create a Hyper-V External Switch (say 'VMDataExternal_vSwitch') and point it to the 'VMData' adapter, then configure my VM's to use the 'VMDataExternal_vSwitch'

**OR**

2. Create a Hyper-V External Switch (say 'VMDataExternal_vSwitch') and point it to the 'Converged-vSW' NIC Team, then configure my VM's to use the 'VMDataExternal_vSwitch'

**PS.** I had planned on setting vLAN tagging on the Hyper-V switch that will be used by the VMs.

Comment: Why not just make a NIC teaming at Host level ?

Comment: I dont quite get your point?

All of this is configured on a Host level?

Comment: All of this is configured on a Host level?

Unless i am missing the point on how a converged network works, isn't the point to create (at host level) the NIC team, virtual NICS and have them connected to the NIC team, the connect the VM's?

This then utlises the use of all NICs vs having dedicated NICs per role type, eg. Cluster, live migration etc

Here is an example link: https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/virtual-networking-configuration-best-practices/

Comment: Your description of the problem is overall unclear.